# PHP, NetSuite API, Get Report

Tags: php, api, netsuite

Here is the situation. I'm trying to get a report that has been created by the report runner (based on the following URL: https://xxx.app.netsuite.com/app/reporting/reportrunner.nl?cr=878 ).

I do have the API setup and it working for, however, I would like to know how to get reporting information through the API?

Thank you,
Kevin Davis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no public API of SuiteCloud that can get the saved report data in either suitescript 1.0 or 2.0.

However, there is a private function in suitescript 1.0 that can run report and get data thru API: var pivotTable = nlapiRunReport(<report_id>, <report_settings>);

There is no official document for this API, if you want to use it, you have to debug it to find out.

Charles

Comment: Thank you for the answer.. That is all I need to know.

Comment: do you know what report_settings I can pass?

Comment: I guess you can use nlapiCreateReportDefinition() to get the report_setting